# PCL not properly installed with vcpkg

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, vcpkg

I've installed the PCL with the vcpkg using `./vcpkg install pcl:x64-windows`. 
After a while I've noticed that concave_hull.h, convex_hull.h and qhull.h are not installed with the rest of the library.
Additional information of what I'm working with:

- vcpkg tag (2020.11.01)
- OS Windows 10
- VS Community 16.8.3

For completion's sake I've included the code which lead me to this problem:

```
#include <pcl/surface/concave_hull.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
int main()
{
    using point_cloud_colored = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>;
    //plane is generated from somewhere else and is not important for this issue
    point_cloud_colored::Ptr plane = load_cloud_from_somewhere(); 
    point_cloud_colored::Ptr hull_cloud(new point_cloud_colored);
    pcl::ConcaveHull<point_cloud_colored> chull;
    chull.setInputCloud(plane);
    chull.setAlpha(0.1);
    chull.reconstruct(*hull_cloud);
}
```

This code produces the following error message:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1083   **Cannot open include file: 'pcl/surface/concave_hull.h': No such file or directory**   farrao_gui  C:\Users\ ...\farrao\source\farrao_gui\farrao_gui.cpp   39

I've already tried to reinstall via vcpkg but with no success. 
Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I solved the problem by switching to the reentrant qhull version following this guide: http://www.qhull.org/html/README_r.txt.

You have to copy the concave_hull code into files (hpp, h and cpp) within your own project.

Fix the headers and remove the `#ifdef HAVE_QHULL` in every file and add this chunk of code within your hpp file:

```
extern "C"
{
#include <libqhull_r/qhull_ra.h>
qhT qh_qh;
qhT* qh = &qh_qh;
}
```

After that:

- Replace every `qh` Makro with `qh->`
- go through every `qh_...` function and add the `qh` pointer as the first parameter (if necessary)
- go through every `FOREACHvertex_i_` Makro and add `qh` as the first parameter

This is probably not the best solution since this problem is well out of my league but the algorithm does generate results. It might also work with the convex algorithm (since it is also not included within the vcpkg installation). 
I hope this answer might be helpful to someone with a similar problem.

Comment: I tested this approach with the convex algorithm and it works as well.